# Clarification on when cancelByProducingResumeData calls completion handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

The Apple documentation has following example for getting background execution time and doing some tasks after app ha been put into the background.  What is the advantage of doing the task using dispatch_async?  I.e. when the app is in the background what is the difference between doing the work on "main thread" vs "asynchronously on background thread"?

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
    // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
    // stopped or ending the task outright.
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

   // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

     [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
     bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting I see two issues if you don't call dispatch_async. If you are executing long running tasks (for e.g do something within a while loop), then this won't allow the app to restart if you try to bring it back to the foreground.  Also, I am seeing that any networking delegates are not called even if app receives data from the far end.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you have 5 seconds to perform any tasks in the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` and return. In case you need additional time - you have to use `beginBackgroundTaskWithName:`.

> In practice, you should return from applicationDidEnterBackground: as
>   quickly as possible. If the method does not return before time runs
>   out your app is terminated and purged from memory.

That is why you should request additional background execution via `beginBackgroundTaskWithName:` call and run the task asynchronously on some thread. In this way you will follow that "5 seconds" rule.

Comment: The 5 second rule only seems to apply if I don't call beginBackgroundTaskWithName .  I.e once I call beginBackgroundTaskWithName, I saw no issue from "iOS killing my app due to 5s expiry" if entered a while(1) loop synchronously.  The only issue I found is that this will app unresponsive when it is relaunched.